# How to use both CfT (Chrome for Testing) and chromedriver lacal binaries with Serenity BDD configuration

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I want to use local binaries instead of downloading them automaticaly by Selenium buit-in WebDriverManager

Here is my serenity.conf

```
serenity {
    take.screenshots = FOR_FAILURES
    headless.mode = false
}

webdriver {
  driver = chrome
  chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe
  capabilities {
    "goog:chromeOptions" {
      binary = src/test/resources/chrome-win64/chrome.exe
      args = ["--start-maximized"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is output:
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 121, returning the closest version; found: 119; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 121